# 3D pie chart: legend is too big

Tags: r

The problem of legend is too big.
When I change the number of cex ,the font is too small and the box is still big.
I hope the box and test can be matched.They will not too small and big.

```
table <- data.frame(num = c(90, 26, 28, 39, 98),
                            countries = c("India","Sri Lanka","Nepal","Bhutan", "China"))
label <-paste(table[,1],"%",sep="")
pie3D(table$num, labels = label, main = "Chart",radius = 1, explode = 0)
par(xpd = TRUE)
legend(1, 0.7, legend = table$countries, cex=0.7, yjust=0.6, xjust = -0.1, 
       fill = heat.colors(length(table$num)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the `pointsize` or the resolution (`width` and `height`) of the image. Than you have as well to adapt the `labelcex`.

```
bmp("plot.bmp", height=600, width=800, pointsize = 15)

pie3D(table$num,labels=label,main="Chart",radius = 1,explode = 0, labelcex=1)
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(1,0.7,legend=table$countries,cex=0.7,yjust=0.2, xjust = -0.1,
       fill = heat.colors(length(table$num)))  

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: when I use plot zoom ,the problem is still here.

Comment: `plot zoom` i dont know about this... I suggest you change the `pointsize` of the image file you creating.